# JIRA - Step description in transition screen

Tags: workflow, jira, issue-tracking

I want to display a text field with the description of the transition, not only input fields. Where can i configure it?

Regards!

João.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the JIRA Toolkit plugin to create a message custom field which are used "to add arbitrary HTML to edit and view pages"

https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/5142

Given that it supports velocity, it should be possible to retrieve the description of the transition from the context ...

[AbstractWorkflowTransition.getDescription()](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/web/action/admin/workflow/AbstractWorkflowTransition.html#getDescription())